# Python Eve Custom Endpoints, but with data pulled from database

Tags: rest, flask, eve

I'm working on an RSS Reader using Python Eve. I have a users schema declared like so:

```
user_info_schema = {
     'username':{
         'type': 'string'
     },
    'feeds':{
        'type': 'list',
    }
 }
```

So in the list I have a list of RSS feed urls. I'd like to make a custom endpoint that grabs the RSS content from the urls and displays them for my client to consume. So I write:

```
@app.route('/api/username/<_id>/feeds')
def view_feed_content(_id):
    users = app.data.driver.db['users']
    a = users.find_one({'_id':_id})
    print(a)
    return "Test"
```

But I get nothing. Everytime I try to get data from my database it just fails and all my queries return None. I've tried doing this with all my db collections, all sorts of different queries. I just can't get custom endpoints to "find" my database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change your lookup to find `_id` with type `ObjectId`, like this:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

a = users.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(_id)})
```

Comment: That was it and I feel dumb. Next time I'll have to do more testing before I go right to stack overflow. Thanks!